# How to get the value in angularJS from the input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get the value of `name2`?

```js
function DemoController($scope) {
    $scope.name1 = 'LISA';
    //How can I get the value of name2?
    console.log($scope.name2) //this does not work
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoController">
    {{ name1 }}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Lisa" ng-model="name2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your not initialize the `name2` inside the controller. so there is no property called `name2` in the scope at the moment of `console.log` . and `name2` property will create on the scope right after your first change on the input. so thats why its getting `undefined`.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbsjibhE3bpGNOKc1wWJ?p=preview), check the console.

```
$scope.$watch('name2', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("new value : " + newVal);
    console.log("old value : " + oldVal);
});
```

i have added a `$watch` on `name2` property (and this `$watch` function will execute when changing the value of `name2`), note that its `undefined` first and it will take the value of input right after you type something in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoController">
  {{ name2 }}
  <input type="text" placeholder="Lisa" ng-model="name2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your controller is running before $scope.name2 even existed yet. You should have the console report the changes at some point AFTER. Remove that line from your code. (console.log...)

Whenever the text in name2 changes, $scope.name2 will be set to that value. You can see the effect if you ADD the following to the controller:

```
$scope.saveChanges = function () {
  alert($scope.name2);
}
```

And to the HTML:

```
<button ng-click="saveChanges()">See Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to follow me on this one.
On the first execution of the script, the variable (or property - doesn't really matter for this topic) is not declared.
Once the interpreter reaches the `console.log` function, it tries to call `name2`'s value, But as we said - it is not defined.
In order to log the data you're binding, you should implement some logic that executes `console.log` only after a change or maybe even using `$scope.apply`. (I believe that `$scope.apply` is too far for you right now and you should ignore it).
Bottom line is - Your variable is not defined for the first iteration, therefore you're getting this result.

Answer (score 0):

You must submit form to get Values  or you use Watch Function

```js
function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.name1 = 'LISA';
 

   
$scope.submitName = function () {
 console.log($scope.name2)
}    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoController">
  {{ name1 }}
  <input type="text" placeholder="Lisa" ng-model="name2">
<button ng-click="submitName()">click </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

name 2 will change as you type in the input box. You can see this by adding

```
{{name2}}
```

to your html

the controller will not see the change in name2 unless you watch for it, you can do this using $watch, add this to your controller

```
   $scope.$watch('name2', function() {
    console.log($scope.name2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ng model in watch for getting the updates

```js
function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.name1 = 'LISA';



 //this will work

 $scope.$watch(function(val){
  if(val){ 
 console.log($scope.name2);
 }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoController">
  {{ name1 }}
  <input type="text" placeholder="Lisa" ng-model="name2">
</div>
```